# AWS Cloud9 `process.versions.node` undefined?

Tags: node.js, aws-cloud9

I've just tried moving a project from the old c9.io to the new AWS c9. But when I try to run the project (a create-react-app project), I get a

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

referring to a reference to `process.versions.node` being expected by the cloudinary npm package

```
module.exports = Number(process.versions.node[0]) < 8 ? require('./lib-es5/cloudinary') : req...
```

How do I go about defining `process.versions.node`?

Answer (score 0):

just print the event, as follows.and you would see process.env.Node_Version(kind of variable not sure of variable name) but you would be able to get the runtime version.

```
   exports.handler = function (event, context, callback){
     console.log(event);
     callback(null, 200);
   }
```